# Is there an FHIR Extension to indicate a Practitioner or Patient Resource has been validated against a registry

Tags: hl7-fhir

When I construct a Patient or Provider resource from incoming data I query a registry to confirm the incoming data is correct.

What I'd like to do is put a field in the resource to notify the receiving system that the data is either correct or is out of sync with the registry. I cold create my own extension, however wondering if an extension currently or will soon exit?

I've reviewed the HL FHIR site and cannot find reference to an extension like this

Answer (score 0):

The [VerificationResult](http://hl7.org/fhir/verificationresult.html) resource is intended for that purpose, as if you're interested in verification information it's typically more than just a simple boolean - at least when the data is being shared outside a tight context where the verifying entity, verification mechanism, etc. might be able to be implicit.